# Where can I find the tafsir of Avicenna?

Tags: quran, tafseer, source-identification, islamic-philosophy

Corbin, in his *History of Islamic Philosophy* quotes from the Tafsir of Avicenna, on Surah 113:

> I seek refuge in the Lord of Day break (verse 1).

Avicenna writes:

> This means: I seek refuge with him who shatters the darkness of non-being with the light of being, and who is the primordial Principle, the Being who is necessary of himself. And this (burst of light), as inhering in his absolute goodness, resides as primal intention in his very ipseity. The first of the beings who emanate from him—the first Intelligence—is its Emanation. Evil does not exist in it, other than that which is occulted beneath the outspreading light of the First Being—the opacity, that is to say, inherent in the quiddity which proceeds from its essence.

I'd like to find where this quote is from - either online, or more likely some book.

Answer (score 7):

In one of his articles, Jules Janssens gave the following piece of information about Avicenna's comments on the Qurʾān:

> Six (or perhaps more correctly, five) such fragments seem to have circulated as independent treatises and have been edited by ʿĀṣī. They concern S. 24, v. 35 (the famous "Light-verse"); S. 41, 11-12a (Then He directed Himself...); S. 87 (The Most High); S. 112 (Purity) and S.113-114 ("Dawn" and "Man"), which constitute a unity in Avicenna’s comment.

The book by Ḥasan ʿĀṣī which contains his edition of the fragments was published in 1983 under the title *Al-Tafsīr al-qurʾānī wa-l-luġa al-ṣūfīya fī falsafat Ibn Sīnā*.

I'd recommend to buy the book. However, If you cannot find it for sale and your local library does not have it, you could try to google the first two words of the title in correct Arabic script in between quotation marks ("  ") and add *pdf* -- maybe you'll be lucky and find a source.

If you're interested in Janssen's article: Jules Janssens, "Avicenna and the Qurʾān. A Survey of his Qurʾānic Commentaries". In: *MIDEO* 25-26 (2004), pp.177-192.

Comment: For reference, the full title in Arabic script would be "التفسير القرآني واللغة الصوفية في فلسفة ابن سينا"

Answer (score 5):

lately in Iran , the researcher of Islamic mysticism and philosophy, Manochehr  Sadoqi Saha published a collections including commentaries by philosophers and Mystics. the complete address of the book is as follow:
    سلسله المختارات من نصوص تفسیر المستنبط،القسم الثانی و هو المقدمه الحاویه علی تفاسیر عقلیه لفلاسفه الهیین،انتشارات حکمت، تهران، ایران،1431 هجری قمری

he point to the commentary of Avicenna in page:63-66

I mention some part of it in Arabic:

> 1-قوله تعالی:قل اعوذ برب الفلق :فالق ظلمه العدم بنور الوجود هو المبدا
>   الاول الواجب الوجود لذاته و ذلک من لوازم خیریته المطلقه الفائضه عن
>   هویته المقصوده بالقصد الاول
>
> 2-و اول الموجودات الصادره عنه هو قضاوه و لیس فیه شر اصلا الا ما صار
>   مخفیا تحت سطوع نور الاول و هو الکدره اللازمه لماهیتها المنشاه من
>   هویتها.

if you want I mention the whole of it, there is no problem. please ask me.

Comment: Thanks. Enhance the answer by providing the english translation of this sentence.

Comment: @ muhammad Hossein:thanks...the translation of this two quotes mentioned in  above question because f this, I don mention it again.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can download a pdf version of a partial [Tafsir of Surah al-Ikhlas](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://traditionalhikma.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Avicennas-philosophical-tafsir-of-Surat-al-Ikhlas.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiZ-Mmfr4rkAhXhpYsKHd7tC4QQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw1_bvpPkgL3tX09oWhZn4Su) by Avicenna.